Correction for n pipe function
I have tried studying on Linux Internals for a month, and I had tried to create n pipes for n+1 functions but something is going wrong, and I couldn't figure out what's going wrong. So, I submit my code upon everyone's attention, and I need someone help me with this
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0,pp[5],j = 0,fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    while(argv[i])
    {
        if(!strcmp(argv[i],"|"))
        {
            argv[i] = '\0';
            pp[j++] = i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < j;i++)
    {
        if(i < j-1)
            pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid)
        {
            int stat;
            wait(&stat);
            dup(fd[1]);
            close(fd[1]);
            close(0);
            dup(fd[0]);
            execvp(argv[pp[i]+1],argv + (pp[i]+1));
        }
        else
        {
            dup(fd[0]);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(1);
            dup(fd[1]);
            execvp(argv[pp[i]],argv + pp[i]);
        }
    }
}


Can you be more specific about what "is going wrong"?  And what this should do if everything goes correctly?

whats going wrong is that always sending empty data to the latter function, it never shows error but the latter function never receives correct data, and if correct it must handle any number of pipes

@SanjaiS Please post input used.

i used ls | wc and ls -­l | grep “pattern” | wc -­l, and it not returning required result

if(i < j-1) pid_t pid = fork(); if(pid) is strange.   The 2nd pid can't use the first pid, so where is it declared?  Try compiling the posted code.  Alos p1 in p1 = dup(fd[0]); is not declared.

i read that for n functions n-1 times fork can be called so, it creates n childs, if(pid) is the parent, and else part would be the child

Am I correctly reading that you're creating only one FIFO, instead of one per pair of processes you need to connect? That won't work; you'll want a separate pipe for each place you connect the stdout of one process to the stdin of another. Moreover, you'll want to be sure no process has an open copy of a FIFO created for the use of a different process.

Updated code still does not compile.  Post a [mcve].  It needs at least 3 include files and other code fixes.

What you're doing here is a very common exercise that students get tripped up by frequently -- I have a hard time believing there's no already answered duplicate in our knowledge base.

i mean that im in an rookie to midway level, so, i could not understand others code, and i am comfortable to be corrected within my code, so i can learn better from myself

argv[i] = '\0'; is valid, but questionable.  argv[i] = NULL; would be better style if that's indeed what you meant.  And if that's not what you meant then it's nevertheless equivalent to what you actually said.

Using more descriptive names for your variables would help everyone, including you.

Re "it not returning required result", What does happen?

Re "I had tried to create n pipes", No, you just created one. And btw, you only need n-1 of them (where n is the number of children).

@ikegami "n pipes for n+1 functions" is the same as "n-1 pipes for n functions".

In your main loop, you fork() and then both parent and child perform an execvp().  That leaves no processes running the loop, and therefore no way to connect n commands if n is greater than 2.

I meant n pipes is that for more than 1 pipe

if thats the case, how can i correct it by running the loop, a prototype smth like that

Note also that you have to be careful with how you run your program.  You're expecting sometimes to receive | as a program argument, so you'll need to escape or quote that on the command line to prevent the shell from which you launch the program handling that itself.

My bad. But the main point stands. You only create one pipe, not n. You said you created n, but you didn't. You should create n, but you didn't. Don't forget to close all the relevant handles where appropriate.

        if(pid)
        {
            // ...
            execvp(argv[pp[i]+1],argv + (pp[i]+1));
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
            execvp(argv[pp[i]],argv + pp[i]);
        }

n must be 1.
I suggest you rebuild your algorithm from the ground up. Something like (pseudocode)
set argmarker = 0
for each argument
   if argument == "|"
      create pipe
      create child process
      if child process
         dup2 pipe output to handle 1
         close pipe handles
         exec()
      dup2 pipe input to handle 0
      close pipe handles
      set argmarker = next argument
if any arguments left
   exec()

Also I omitted error handling; you need to check if pipe(), fork() or exec() fail.
